# How to visualize Reverse Triangle Inequality $||\mathbf{a}| − |\mathbf{b}|| ≤ |\mathbf{a} − \mathbf{b}|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, intuition, visualization

pp [152](https://books.google.com/books?id=OdrDAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA294&lpg=PA294&dq=%22this+is+the+donkey+theorem%22&source=bl&ots=XGa-x8DRWU&sig=ACfU3U2zJJtumTzcKIcn3xxpuQHH_eM-8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBsfHtv-bqAhVHgnIEHcNYBcYQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [294](https://books.google.ca/books?id=OdrDAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA294&lpg=PA294&dq=%22this+is+the+donkey+theorem%22&source=bl&ots=XGa-x8DRWU&sig=ACfU3U2zJJtumTzcKIcn3xxpuQHH_eM-8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBsfHtv-bqAhVHgnIEHcNYBcYQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false),  [Kuldeeph Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step* (2013)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00G96ZJ8W) illustrates Triangle Inequality. But without referring to Triangle Inequality at all, how to picture  Reverse Triangle Inequality for all $\mathbf{a,b} \in C^n$? I don't want proofs or rigour.

[image]

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: @SantoshLinkha is there intuition or figure please for Reverse Triangle Inequality

Comment: of course, there is ... think about vectors.

Comment: Triangle with vertices $0, a, b$.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "referring to the triangle inequality at all"? $\bigl||a|-|b|\bigr|\le|a-b|$ is equivalent to $|a|-|b|\le|a-b|$ and $|b|-|a|\le|a-b|$, both of which easily follow from the triangle inequality on the triangle that Daniel Fischer mentioned.

Comment: [Does this help](http://i.imgur.com/toRVVaq.png)?

Answer (score 10):

Let do this in terms of vector ...

[image]

sorry for bad drawing. I hope you will understand :D

ADDED: Here is clarification as you requested.
The length $|a| = AD = AE $ because they are radius of the same circle. And $|b| = AC$ so $||a|-|b|| = EC = AC - AE$

Comment: and how did you calculate or form $||\mathbf{a}| − |\mathbf{b}|| $?

Comment: @TuckerRapu I have added the details as you requested.

Comment: +upvote. consummate picture! last question. so you are saying we can see $AC - AE \le CD$, whereever point c is? the difference is not too clear to me. thanks.  Please apprise me in your answer? Not in comments please.

Comment: @TuckerRapu the point C is at the right corner of the triangle near point 8. Point $E$ is near 4

Comment: thanks again. can you please demystify how your picture shows  $EC \le DE$ without doubt ? to me, it looks like you can draw the picture so $EC \not \le DE $?

Answer (score 4):

Draw two circles as follows:

[image]

Let $z_1$ be any complex number on the larger red circle and $z_2$ be any complex number on the smaller black circle. Note that $|z_1|$ and $|z_2|$ are the radii of the red circle and black circle respectively.

$\big||z_1| - |z_2|\big|$ (purple on the real axis) is always some positive number representing the absolute value of the difference between these radii.

$|z_1 - z_2|$ (blue) is a positive number representing the distance between $z_1$ and $z_2$ (some different choices for $z_1$ and $z_2$ are shown)

As you can see no matter how you choose the points on the red and black circle, the inequality
$$||z_1| - |z_2||≤|z_1 - z_2|$$ holds

The smallest distance between two points on two concentric circles is the difference between the circles's radii.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition is that the inequality is equality whenever there's no cancellation happening. I'll keep this in the reals but the idea generalises. Suppose that $a,b > 0$. Then
\begin{equation}
| |a| - |b| | = |a - b|
\end{equation}
whereas, if $a > 0 > b$, then
\begin{align}
| |a| - |b| | &= | a + b | \leq \max\{|a|, |b|\} \leq \max\{a, -b\} \leq \max\{a, -b\} + \min\{-b, a\} = a - b \\ &= |a - b|
\end{align}

If you want to think more geometrically then $|a - b|$ is the size of the vector from $b$ to $a$ which is minimised when they're both pointing in the same direction and, at that minimum, is the LHS above. When they're not pointing in the same direction then $|a - b|$ is bigger but $||a| - |b||$ stays the same size (as it doesn't care about the angle between $a$ and $b$).