# What is the geometric interpretation of reverse triangle inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

In almost every book of real analysis, geometric interpretation of triangle inequality is mentioned.

But what is the geometric interpretation of reverse triangle inequality.

$$||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$$

I know this inequality is used to show that norm function is continuous. Are there any other ways to geometrically interpret the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition or figure for Reverse Triangle Inequality $||\mathbf{a}| − |\mathbf{b}|| ≤ |\mathbf{a} − \mathbf{b}|$ (Abbott p 11 q1.2.5)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774197/intuition-or-figure-for-reverse-triangle-inequality-mathbfa-%e2%88%92-mathbfb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length difference between any two sides of a triangle is always smaller than that of the third. Does this count?

Answer (score 1):

I added color and vector names to Najib Idrissi's picture for more contrast and detail.

> [Does this help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNnL7.png)?– [Najib Idrissi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10014/najib-idrissi) [Apr 29 '14 at 14:02](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774197/how-to-visualize-reverse-triangle-inequality-mathbfa-%e2%88%92-mathbfb-%e2%89%a4#comment1606735_774197)

[image]