# While pictorializing $|x - y| < |x + y|$, how can solely 1 picture simultaneously prove (Reverse) △ Inequalities, $|x-y| ≤ |x|+|y|, |x|-|y| ≤ |x-y|$?

Tags: visualization, triangle-inequality

On p. 12, Michael Spivak's *Calculus* (2008 4 edn) proved $|x + y| ≤ \color{darkgoldenrod}{|x| + |y|}$ (Triangle Inequality).
Ibid, exercise 12, p. 16.

> (iv) ${\color{red}{|x-y|}} ≤ \color{goldenrod}{|x| + |y|}$. (Give a very short proof.)
> (v) ${\color{limegreen}{|x|-|y|}} ≤ {\color{red}{|x-y|}}$. (A very short proof is possible, if you write things in the right way).

(vi)  $\left|{\color{limegreen}{|x|-|y|}}\right| ≤ |x  - y|$ (Why does this follow immediately from (v)?)
**[This (vi) is  Reverse Triangle Inequality, but I deleted Spivak's superfluous set of round brackets.]**

##### How can *one and same* picture  prove all 4 inequalities above? Please contrast $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ so that visibly,  $|\vec{x} - \vec{y}| < |\vec{x} + \vec{y}|$. You can use my improvement of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/774233).

[image]

Comment: Please fix your image. Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Done. Thanks.